# Xamarin expired Visual Studio not opening project for viewing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, licensing

Situation: Some time ago I wrote an Android app using Xamarin.Android for Visual Studio . I've since learned some Java and wish to port my Original App over using Eclipse.

Problem: My subscription has lapsed for the Xamarin.Android and now Visual Studio gives me a Dialog Window telling me about it. I do not wish to renew my licence as I will not be using the Dev Tool for any future work. But now I'm completely locked (Dialog either closes project or insists on renewal) out of opening the Mobile App Solution in Visual Studio.

Want: Workaround to still open solution I don't want to build or deploy using VS at all. I also don't want to have to open up each code file in Notepad just to be able to see my code. Is there a line I can simply remove/modify in the .csproj so I can open it normally? Or can Xamarin provide me with a winning solution that won't cost an arm and a leg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each Xamarin project open the .csproj file and in the ProjectTypeGuids element remove the values other than `{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}`, which is the vanilla C# project type. That should stop Visual Studio trying to load the Xamarin extensions.